# Сигналы Django, как вытащить m2m id перед отправкой данных

Tags: python, django

Есть проблема с Django, а именно с сигналом.

Есть модель в которой есть поле m2m.
Нужно по созданию новой записи вытащить все id с m2m и в другой таблице создать новые записи с этими id.
При post_save django делает query запрос, но делает к таблице m2m, но данные в неё еще не попали, т.к. post_save делает перед тем, как внести данные в таблицу m2m
Как реализовать это?

Comment: [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)?

Comment: я не изменяю значения m2m, я добавляю запись, где есть m2m.при m2m_changed дебагер не останавливается

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет m2m-changed сигнал.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed